# How to delete record in laravel via ajax

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I know there are similar questions relating to this issue, but I have tried my copy after those with the right answer, yet still to no avail.
I keep getting this error:

> BadMethodCallException Method delete does not exist. in Macroable.php (line 74)

To be quick, here is my controller:

```
public function destroy(Subject $subject)
{
    //
    $response = array();

    $modal = new Subject; 
    $modal = Subject::find($subject);

    if ( $modal->delete() ) {
        $response['success'] = '<b>'.$modal->name.'</b>'.' successfully deleted';
        $response['subject'] = $modal;   
    }

    return \Response::json($response);

}
```

Here is my route:

```
Route::delete('/subjects/delete/{subject}', 'SubjectsController@destroy');
```

Here is my view:

```
<td>
    <a data-token="{{ csrf_token() }}" id="delete" data-id="{{$subject->id}}" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit" href="/subjects/{{$subject->id}}" role="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash text-danger"></i></a>
</td>
```

and last my scripts:

```
$(document).on('click', '#delete', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            /* Act on the event */

            // id of the row to be deleted
            var id = $(this).attr('data-id');

            var token = $(this).data("token");

            console.log(id);

            // row to be deleted
            var row = $(this).parent("td").parent("tr");

            var message = "subject";

             bootbox.dialog({
                message: "Are you sure you want to Delete this "+message+"?",
                title: "<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></i> Delete !",
                buttons: {
                    success: {
                        label: "No",
                        className: "btn-success",
                        callback: function() {
                            $('.bootbox').modal('hide');
                        }
                    },
                    danger: {
                        label: "Delete!",
                        className: "btn-danger",
                        callback: function() {

                            $.ajaxSetup({
                                headers: {
                                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                                }
                            });

                            $.ajax({
                                type: 'DELETE',
                                url: '/subjects/delete/'+id,
                                data: {
                                    "id": id,
                                    "_method": 'DELETE',
                                    "_token": token
                                }
                            })
                           .done(function(response){
                                bootbox.alert(response.success);
                                //removing the row that have been deleted
                                jQuery(row).fadeOut('slow');
                            })
                           .fail(function(){
                                bootbox.alert('Something Went Wrong .... Please contact administrator');
                            })
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

Here is what I get when I don `php artisan route:list`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the technical details of why it is working this way but it seems the the problem was coming from my controller destroy method. So, this was all I had to do:

controller code:

```
public function destroy($subject)
{
    //
    $response = array();

    $modal = new Subject; 
    $modal = Subject::find($subject);

    if ( $modal->delete() ) {
        $response['success'] = '<b>'.$modal->name.'</b>'.' successfully deleted';
        $response['subject'] = $modal;   
    }

    return \Response::json($response);

}
```

script:

```
callback: function() {

                            $.ajaxSetup({
                                headers: {
                                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                                }
                            });

                            $.ajax({
                                type: 'DELETE',
                                url: '/subjects/delete/'+id,
                                data:{"id": id, "_method": 'DELETE'}
                            })
                           .done(function(response){
                                bootbox.alert(response.success);
                                //removing the row that have been deleted
                                jQuery(row).fadeOut('slow');
                            })
                           .fail(function(){
                                bootbox.alert('Something Went Wrong .... Please contact administrator');
                            })
                        }
```

route:

```
Route::delete('/subjects/delete/{subject}','SubjectsController@destroy');
```

The main thing for me was to remove the `Subject` from the `destroy()` parameter and it work.
If any of you know why it's working that please provide and explanation so that I can understand it too. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Change the type in your ajax call to POST, the _method field in the data object is all that is needed. This is how your ajax call should look. Laravel "fakes" the DELETE method by using the _method field to determine the http verb.

```js
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/subjects/delete/'+id,
    data: {
        "_method": 'DELETE',
        "_token": token
    }
})
.done(function(response){
    bootbox.alert(response.success);
    //removing the row that have been deleted
    jQuery(row).fadeOut('slow');
})
.fail(function(){
    bootbox.alert('Something Went Wrong .... Please contact administrator');
})
```

Comment: What does php artisan route:list show you about the route?

Comment: don't know what actually you want to know so I'm adding a picture of the result I got from php artisan route:list. You can check the update of this post.

Comment: Shouldn't you be including api middleware since you're doing this via ajax?

Comment: thanks but that wasn't the problem for me, just figured it out. About to post a answer of how I got it working. Appreciate your effort.

Comment: Good to hear you figured it out, I'm interested to see what the issue was.